# SQLite Delete multiple rows with group by and join two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables. The first is Chats table contain messages of current user with friend. And the second table is Threads which save thread chat (A thread chat of user with friend - contain multiple messages)

What I want is: thread chat 1 I want to delete x messages, thread chat 2 delete y messages, thread 3 delete z messages...

How can I achieve it in 1 sql query ?

Column of each table as below:

Table Chats: msgId, threadId, messages, timestamp.

Table Threads: threadId, displayName.

[image: Data example for Thread table]

[image: Data example for Chat table]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the [help] pages, take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Also please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Via a temporary table to store how many records to keep.
And through using a trick to simulate a ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION.

**Setup Sample Data:**

```
drop table IF EXISTS TestThreads;
create Table TestThreads (threadId INTEGER NOT NULL primary key, displayName TEXT);
drop table IF EXISTS TestChats;
create Table TestChats (msgId INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTOINCREMENT, threadId INTEGER, "timestamp" DATETIME, messages TEXT);

--
-- Sample Data
--
delete from TestThreads;
insert into TestThreads (threadId, displayName) values
 (1,'Superman')
,(2,'Son Goku')
,(3,'Bai Xiaochun')
;

delete from TestChats;
insert into TestChats (threadId, "timestamp", messages) values 
 (1,'2018-01-01 11:15:01','It is not')
,(1,'2018-01-01 11:15:02','an S')
,(1,'2018-01-01 11:15:03','on my world')
,(1,'2018-01-01 11:15:04','it means hope')
,(2,'2018-01-01 12:15:01','Kame')
,(2,'2018-01-01 12:15:02','Hame')
,(2,'2018-01-01 12:15:03','Hhhaaa')
,(2,'2018-01-01 12:15:04','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
,(3,'2018-01-01 13:15:01','When')
,(3,'2018-01-01 13:15:02','I start deleting')
,(3,'2018-01-01 13:15:03','I frighten')
,(3,'2018-01-01 13:15:04','even myself')
 ;
```

**Put the threadId's with the number in a temporary table:**

```
--
-- create and fill temporary table
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _tmpThreadsToCleanup;
CREATE TEMP TABLE _tmpThreadsToCleanup(threadId int primary key, NrToDel int);

DELETE FROM _tmpThreadsToCleanup;
INSERT INTO _tmpThreadsToCleanup(threadId, NrToDel)
SELECT threadId, 3 as NrToDel from TestThreads where displayName = 'Superman' UNION ALL
SELECT threadId, 2 as NrToDel from TestThreads where displayName = 'Son Goku' UNION ALL
SELECT threadId, 1 as NrToDel from TestThreads where displayName = 'Bai Xiaochun'
;
```

**The Deletion:**

```
--
-- Delete messages based on the counts in the temporary table
--
DELETE 
FROM TestChats
WHERE msgId IN (
   SELECT c.msgId
    FROM TestChats AS c
    JOIN _tmpThreadsToCleanup AS r on (r.threadId = c.threadId)
    WHERE (select count(*) from TestChats c2 WHERE c2.threadId = c.threadId AND c2.msgID <= c.msgId) <= r.NrToDel
);
```

**Query what remains:**

```
SELECT th.threadId, th.displayName, ch.msgId, ch."timestamp", ch.messages
FROM TestThreads AS th
LEFT JOIN TestChats AS ch on (ch.threadId = th.threadId)
ORDER BY th.threadId, ch.msgId;
```

**Result:**

```
threadId displayName msgId timestamp           messages
-------- ----------- ----- ------------------- ------------
1        Superman      4   2018-01-01 11:15:04 it means hope
2        Son Goku      7   2018-01-01 12:15:03 Hhhaaa
2        Son Goku      8   2018-01-01 12:15:04 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3        Bai Xiaochun 10   2018-01-01 13:15:02 I start deleting
3        Bai Xiaochun 11   2018-01-01 13:15:03 I frighten
3        Bai Xiaochun 12   2018-01-01 13:15:04 even myself
```

**Remarks:**

Because of that join on the count(*) per record to mimic ROW_NUMBER that method should be quite the slowpoke.

But if the numbers of records to delete is the same for the selected threads then LIMIT could be used instead.

```
DELETE 
FROM TestChats 
WHERE msgId IN (
   SELECT c.msgId
    FROM TestChats AS c
    JOIN _tmpThreadsToCleanup AS r on (r.threadId = c.threadId)
    WHERE c.threadId = TestChats.threadId
    ORDER BY c.msgID ASC
    LIMIT 2 -- Fixed number
);
```

If you would want to do the opposite, and keep N records then a LIMIT with an OFFSET can be used for that.  The order by should be descending then.
The benefit of that is that such query won't remove extra records when you run it a second time.

```
DELETE
FROM TestChats 
WHERE msgId IN (
   SELECT c.msgId
    FROM TestChats AS c
    JOIN _tmpThreadsToCleanup AS r on (r.threadId = c.threadId)
    WHERE c.threadId = TestChats.threadId
    ORDER BY c.msgID DESC
    LIMIT -1 OFFSET 2 -- Fixed number
);
```

Comment: Thank you for nice solution, but your solution can not solve the problem if the number of threads is undefined

Comment: @AllenWalker  So you're looking for a solution where the Thread displayNames aren't hardcoded and with a fixed number of messages to delete?  Because in your question it suggested for a different number for each separate thread.

Comment: Each thread have different number of msg to delete. And Thread.displayNames aren't hardcoded, it can be: Allen, Luk, Batman,..I added the screenshot of data example.

Comment: @AllenWalker Changed it.  Now using a temp table.  Btw, personally I would find it safer to keep N records, rather than to remove N records.

Comment: your solution work, but very slow. On my db (about 50k row) it take ~13s

Comment: @AllenWalker I really don't like that method to simulate a ROW_NUMBER with a PARTITION. This would be much easier on a database that would support the SQL standard of window functions. Because it seems terrible ineffecient. The previous solution used LIMIT, which would be much more efficient.  I don't see another way to do this in SQLite atm though.   I know you can replace with IN with an EXISTS, but that wouldn't change the fact that joining to a count for every record is terrible for performance...

Comment: @AllenWalker I see you followed my advice of removing the approvement of my answer. But perhaps also edit your question.  Because then this question will be up again in the list of questions.  Btw, they added the [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) in version 3.25.0.  If you have that version then this solution can surely be simplified.